# unable to send callback to more than one cordova.exec

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am building a phonegap application and have called a java native plugin from it using cordova.exec.
I am stuck somewhere unexpected.

I am calling cordova.exec multiple times in a loop.Also those native plugins are performing async task.But to amazement ,its returning callback only for first cordova.exec() call. I want it to return to javascript at my last cordova.exec() call.

Please help.
My code is as follows----

Javascript code-

```
  $( "input:checked" ).each(function() 
       { 
            cordova.exec(callbacksuccess,callbackerror,'MyPlugin','plugin1',[path,pckg,id]); 
        });
    function callbacksuccess(e)
    {
     alert(e);
    }
    function callbackerror()
    { 
    alert('error');
    }
```

Java Native Plugin code-

```
if (action.equals("plugin1"))
    { 
      new DownloadManager().execute(myurl);
      return true;
    }
   public class DownloadManager extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{  
 @Override
 public String doInBackground(final String... arg0)
 {
     try
     {
         downloadapk(arg0[0]);
         installapk();
         System.out.println("Download Complete");
         PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "success");
         result.setKeepCallback(true);
         callback.success("done");
         return null;
      }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           callback.error("Some problem occured.Try again later");
           return null;
        }                       
}
}
```

Suppose I have 5 listitems selected. It returns "done" just once. callbacksuccess function is called just once for the first cordova.exec function.I didnot find any solution.
Thanx in advance

Comment: are you solved this one how? the below answer is not working for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

1.In your execute() method of your plugin save the callbackId you get and return a NO_RESULT plugin result and set keep callback id to true.

> ```
> PluginResult pluginResult = new  PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT); 
> pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true); 
> return pluginResult;
> ```

2.When your async java method finishes return another plugin result like this:

> ```
> PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, data); 
> result.setKeepCallback(false); 
> this.success(result, this.myCallbackId);
> ```

Comment: Thankyou Sir. I didnot think about it earlier. Your solution solved the mess. Thankyou again.

Comment: Your Welcome,Kindly upvote if you find solution useful.

Comment: actually vote up requires minimum reputation. I have not gained upto it.

Comment: @Aravin Here this is referred to object of CallbackContext and using that object you can get callBackId like: 
    callbackContext.getCallbackId().

Comment: `pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);` with an OK status lets the plugin return progress. It was not clear from the cordova docs.