# How to execute cordova callback (success or error) twice in java

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have the following issue, I receive from cordova 2 callbacks (success and error), and i need to trigger the success callback many times.

The problem is that cordova doesn't seems to allow execute a callback twice, it's only executed once.

```
//Will be executed once, whatever i do, only 1 time
callbacks.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, contenedor.toString()));
// It doesn't trigger anymore of anyway :(
 callbacks.success(contenedor.toString());
 callbacks.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, contenedor.toString()));
 callbacks.success(contenedor.toString());
```

For some reason i need to send a string many times every x time (i want to achieve this executing the succcess callback) and i need to repeat the callback :(

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214210/cordova-callback-return-after-second-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731417/unable-to-send-callback-to-more-than-one-cordova-exec) without success, the success callbacks stills firing just once ! Is there a way to execute a callback easily twice ?

**SOLVED (facepalm)**

If someone have this problem , quick solution :

```
PluginResult resulta = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "first response");
resulta.setKeepCallback(true);
callbacks.sendPluginResult(resulta);

PluginResult resultb = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "2nd response");
resultb.setKeepCallback(true);
callbacks.sendPluginResult(resultb);
```

remember that if is an async call we need to return NO_RESULT first

```
PluginResult pluginResult = new  PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT); 
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true); // Keep callback

        return true; // in execute method
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I jumped into the same issue and then came across this post, so I thought of answering it again for better understanding.

So if you want to receive the callback twice or more then **Don't use the success() method** I repeat **Don't use the success() method**. This is where I was stuck. So only use the following

```
 PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, <Your Result>);
 result.setKeepCallback(true);
 callback.sendPluginResult(result);
```